# Need help in dynamic edit button event in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need help for dynamic edit button event.When i am log in as User I am getting welcome message...welcome user! exactly under this welcome i am putting Edit profile link.So whenever the user click on edit profile he should see only his profile and will be able to edit his profile.Please somebody help me with code.

Thanks,
Masum

Comment: Try asking a specific question

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using the ASP.NET login controls, especially if you are using the membership providers.

```
<asp:LoginView ID="RegisterLink" runat="server">
  <AnonymousTemplate>
    <div class="titleRegistration">
      <a href="/Users/Register.aspx">Register</a> or 
    </div>
  </AnonymousTemplate>
  <LoggedInTemplate>
    <div class="titleRegistration">
      Welcome back
      <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" />
      -
    </div>
  </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
<asp:LoginStatus ID="lsGeneral" runat="server" LogoutPageUrl="/Users/Logout.aspx" />
```

So, what I'm doing here is:

1. Using a [LoginView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx) control to show different information to anonymous users and logged in users - the Anonymous user sees a link to my registration page, and the word "or", the logged in user sees their name (rendered automatically by the [LoginName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginname.aspx) control) and a dash.
2. Using a [LoginStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginstatus.aspx) control to automatically render a "login" or "logout" link depending on whether the user has logged in or out.

This produces the following for anonymous users:

> Register or Login

And for logged in users:

> Welcome back Zhaph - Logout

You could easily add a link on the UserName to go to a general profile page, this would then retrieve the users details from their profile to edit.

Does that help at all?